# Setting Solution Filename on OutDir

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a file set which is a scan for all of the *.sln files in my source tree.  There is currently 4 folders

With the masterParam I am passing in the GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder and setting the outdir

What I am looking to do is for every sln that is being built with the MSBuild to append the solution name as part of the outDir.

I am using F# FAKE

Below is from the Target Build.

```
let masterParam = [
  ("Configuration",buildMode);
  ("GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder","true");
  ("OutDir",("drop/<solutionName>");
  ("BuildInParallel", "false");
]

// compile all projects below src/app/
MSBuild buildDir "Build" masterParam appReferences
  |> Log "Build-Output: "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in any "automatic" way, but since FAKE lets you write arbitrary F# code, you can iterate over the projects and run MSBuild on individual projects.

Something like this should do the trick (you might need to open `System.IO`):

```
for proj in appReferences do
  let name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(proj)
  let masterParam = [
    ("Configuration",buildMode);
    ("GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder","true");
    ("OutDir",("drop/" + name);
    ("BuildInParallel", "false");
  ]

  MSBuild buildDir "Build" masterParam [proj]
  |> Log "Build-Output: "
```

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Also you do need to specify the Open System.IO